# c++, create structs from a database result

Tags: c++, mysql, windows

I’m trying to create structs from a database result. What is an easy way to do this?
I want to get something like this: (This is a small example that doesn’t work. I placed this to make everything clear)

```
struct ROWSTRUCTURE
{
    int ID;
    std::string test;
};

enum ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_end
{
    ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_ID,
    ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_test,
    ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_end
};

list<ROWSTRUCTURE> getData()
{
    MYSQL_ROW row; 
    MYSQL_RES *res_set;

    mysql_query(connect,"SELECT * FROM `example`;");
    res_set = mysql_store_result(connect);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res_set)) != NULL)
    {
        ROWSTRUCTURE StructToAdd;

        for( int i = 0; i < ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_end; i++)
            StructToAdd[i] = row[i]; //ERROR
    }

    delete res_set;
}
```

How can I do this in a correct way?

Comment: Assign the fields one by one (while doing whatever conversion needs doing)?

Comment: Not quite sure what you want to do here. What is `ID` and `test` supposed to contain?

Comment: @ForEveR I want to return a list of these things in the end. I did't made that part jet.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg I want to do that process automatically

Comment: @Mats Petersson That will contain the result of: SELECT * FROM `example`. In the table example there is a field ID and test.

Comment: @Ordo you cannot do that process automatic. You can overload `operator =` in your class, for `MYSQL_ROW` and assign fields in it.

Comment: @ForEveR thanks, then I will do it that way.

Comment: You also need to use [mysql_free_result](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-free-result.html) instead of delete to free res_set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is something called "reflection", where names of variables, member fields etc can be used to refer to the actual variable/field or whatever. C++ does not support this. You will need to solve this in some other way... A plausible solution is:

```
StructToAdd.ID = strtol(row[ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_ID]);
StructToAdd.test = row[ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_test];
```

Or, as the comment suggests:

```
struct ROWSTRUCTURE
{
    int ID;
    std::string test;
    ROWSTRUCTURE operator=(const MYSQL_ROW &row)
    {
        ID = strtol(row[ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_ID]);
        test = row[ROWSTRUCTURE_FIELD_ENUM_test];
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and then in the "main" function:

```
StructToAdd = row;
```